# Asp.Net 5 Music Store Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I just did a fresh clone of the Asp.Net music store on github.  I understand it is using the new Microsoft.AspNetCore.* libraries as well as the EntityFrameworkCore.* libraries so I have feeds for the RC2 configured in VS.  When I load the application for the first time and it restores the packages, I always get this error:

> NU1002    The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0-rc2-16991 in
>   project MusicStore does not support framework
>   DNXCore,Version=v5.0. MusicStore  C:\Users\kyle.36TECHNOLOGY\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2015\Projects\MusicStore-dev\src\MusicStore\project.json

Just to troubleshoot, I've moved that dependency in my project.json file out of 'dnxcore50' and into 'dnx451'.  The error does go away for my project.json reference, but I get 400 errors, because all MVC seems to break?

Comment: I did figure this out.  I had an older version of DNX and had to point my feed to get a newer version.  Once updated everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 2):

rc2 is not stable yet. Try to download the rc1 version https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/releases